# "Error: `x` must be a formula" with qwraps2 summary_table function

Tags: r, summary, qwraps2

I am trying to make a table with summary statistics that looks similar to this (but with min/max/median/mean values filled in):

```
                            Type
Mass (g)        tct    tcx    tht    thx    tct
    Min
    Max
    Median
    Mean (SD)
Length (mm)
    Min
    Max
    Median
    Mean (SD)
Width (mm)
    Min
    Max
    Median
    Mean (SD)
```

Or even like this: (with a width column too)

```
        Mass (g)                         Length (mm)      
Type    Min   Max   Median   Mean (SD)   Min   Max   Median   Mean (SD)
tct
tcx
tht
thx
tct
```

Here is an example of my data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  "id" = c(01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10),
  "type" = c("tct", "tcx", "tht", "thx", "tct"),
  "mass.g" = c(0.03,0.01,0.04,0.06,0.07,0.03,0.03,0.01,0.04,0.02),
  "size.length" = c(8,6,5,6.5,5,5.5,6,7,4,3),
  "size.width" = c(2,4,3,4,5,6,3,4,2,1),
)
```

This is the code I am working on, taken from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qwraps2/vignettes/summary-statistics.html).

```
library(qwraps2)

summary <-
  list("Mass (g)" =
         list(
              "Min" = ~ min(.data$mass.g),
              "Max" = ~ max(.data$mass.g),
              "Median" = ~ median(.data$mass.g)
              "Mean (SD)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$mass.g)),
       "Length (mm)" =
         list(
              "Min" = ~ min(.data$size.length),
              "Max" = ~ median(.data$size.length),
              "Median" = ~ max(.data$size.length),
              "Mean (SD)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$size.length)),
       "Width (mm)" =
         list(
              "Min" = ~ min(.data$size.width),
              "Max" = ~ median(.data$size.width),
              "Median" = ~ max(.data$size.width),
              "Mean (SD)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$size.width)
              ))
summary
```

```
by_type <- summary_table(dplyr::group_by(dat, type), summary)
by_type
```

But I keep getting the error message: "Error: `x` must be a formula"

My end goal is to complete a table that resembles the above and export it as an excel file or word doc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: some minor things noticed: (1) in `dat` dataframe declaration extra comma at end of line with `size.width`; (2) missing comma in `Median` line after `median(.data$mass.g)`; (3) `summary` refers to `data` not `dat`; with those corrected I believe this works

Comment: Ben's first two comments are correct.  (3) is not correct.  The summary structure should use the `.data` pronoun so the scoping is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor correction when building the data set. I used dput() to get the
structure of the object. This is a little more robust than using `data.frame`
as the mode of each column is explicitly defined.

```r
dat <-
 structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), type = structure(c(1L,
 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = c("tct",
 "tcx", "tht", "thx")), mass.g = c(0.03, 0.01, 0.04, 0.06, 0.07,
 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.04, 0.02), size.length = c(8, 6, 5, 6.5,
 5, 5.5, 6, 7, 4, 3), size.width = c(2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2,
 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

loading the qwraps2 package and setting the markup language to “markdown”.
Without this setting the default markup is LaTeX.

```r
library(qwraps2)
options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown")
```

The same summary as in the question posting, but with the missing comma added
as noted in Ben’s comment.

```r
summary <-
  list("Mass (g)" =
       list(
            "Min" = ~ min(mass.g),
            "Max" = ~ max(mass.g),
            "Median" = ~ median(mass.g),
            "Mean (SD)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(mass.g)),
       "Length (mm)" =
         list(
              "Min" = ~ min(size.length),
              "Max" = ~ median(size.length),
              "Median" = ~ max(size.length),
              "Mean (SD)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(size.length)),
       "Width (mm)" =
         list(
              "Min" = ~ min(size.width),
              "Max" = ~ median(size.width),
              "Median" = ~ max(size.width),
              "Mean (SD)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(size.width)
              ))
```

The summary table appears to render as expected:

```r
by_type <- summary_table(x = dat, summaries = summary, by = "type")
by_type
#> 
#> 
#> |                       |tct (N = 4)        |tcx (N = 2)        |tht (N = 2)        |thx (N = 2)        |
#> |:----------------------|:------------------|:------------------|:------------------|:------------------|
#> |**Mass (g)**           |&nbsp;&nbsp;       |&nbsp;&nbsp;       |&nbsp;&nbsp;       |&nbsp;&nbsp;       |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Min       |0.02               |0.01               |0.01               |0.04               |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Max       |0.07               |0.03               |0.04               |0.06               |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Median    |0.03               |0.02               |0.025              |0.05               |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Mean (SD) |0.04 &plusmn; 0.02 |0.02 &plusmn; 0.01 |0.03 &plusmn; 0.02 |0.05 &plusmn; 0.01 |
#> |**Length (mm)**        |&nbsp;&nbsp;       |&nbsp;&nbsp;       |&nbsp;&nbsp;       |&nbsp;&nbsp;       |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Min       |3                  |6                  |5                  |4                  |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Max       |5.25               |6                  |6                  |5.25               |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Median    |8                  |6                  |7                  |6.5                |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Mean (SD) |5.38 &plusmn; 2.06 |6.00 &plusmn; 0.00 |6.00 &plusmn; 1.41 |5.25 &plusmn; 1.77 |
#> |**Width (mm)**         |&nbsp;&nbsp;       |&nbsp;&nbsp;       |&nbsp;&nbsp;       |&nbsp;&nbsp;       |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Min       |1                  |3                  |3                  |2                  |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Max       |3.5                |3.5                |3.5                |3                  |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Median    |6                  |4                  |4                  |4                  |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; Mean (SD) |3.50 &plusmn; 2.38 |3.50 &plusmn; 0.71 |3.50 &plusmn; 0.71 |3.00 &plusmn; 1.41 |
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
#>  os       macOS Catalina 10.15.6      
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       America/Denver              
#>  date     2020-09-15                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  backports     1.1.9   2020-08-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  callr         3.4.4   2020-09-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  cli           2.0.2   2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  devtools      2.3.1   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  digest        0.6.25  2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  htmltools     0.5.0   2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  knitr         1.29    2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  pkgbuild      1.1.0   2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  processx      3.4.4   2020-09-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ps            1.3.4   2020-08-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  qwraps2     * 0.5.0   2020-09-14 [1] local         
#>  R6            2.4.1   2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.5   2020-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  remotes       2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rlang         0.4.7   2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rmarkdown     2.3     2020-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  stringi       1.5.3   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  testthat      2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  usethis       1.6.1   2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  withr         2.2.0   2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  xfun          0.17    2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#> 
#> [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library
```